# Reading network-manager password from another hdd

Tags: network-manager, password, vpn, openvpn, password-recovery

Today I cloned my Ubuntu 11.10 into my old hdd, and installed 12.04 into my current hdd.

What I need now is to recover passwords for my VPN connections on the network manager that is in the old 11.10 cloned hdd, but I don't want to boot it.

I can read and write to that disk from the newly installed Ubuntu 12.04, so where should I look for those passwords?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be correct, but I'm at work and don't have my own systems to look it up on. Try this directory /home/userdir/.gconf/system/networking/connections If not, then it might just be in /home/userdir/.conf/system/networking/connections. I think it's something along the line of nm-settings.conf or just nm.conf. Good luck!!

Comment: I have neither `~/.gconf/system/networking` nor `~/.conf` directories. I believe Network Manager stores passwords in gnome-keyring by default.